# ES6 Import feature is triggering 404 error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export

I am trying to import some function from mylib.js file.

```
import exportedFunction from './mylib.js';
```

However, I am getting this error:

> GET http://localhost/mylib.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

app.js the file from where i am doing the import is located at the same level as the mylib.js

index.html contains the following line:

```
<script type="module" src="app.js" defer></script>
```

Can you, please, tell me what is the issue?

Comment: That should work. Double-check your filenames and locations. For instance, on \*nix, `MyLib.js`, `myLib.js`, `mylib.js`, `mylib.JS`, etc. are all different filenames. Depending on the web server software you're using, case can be significant in URLs, too.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `import exportedFunction from '../mylib.js';`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - The OP clearly said the files are in the same location.

Comment: Side note: Module scripts are automatically deferred, adding `defer` to the `script` tag doesn't have any effect. Details [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) (scroll down a bit until you see an image comparing various `script` tags).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the hint. By the way, I've double checked them, but it is still getting the same error...

Comment: @AbdouBestmood - All due respect, you *must* be missing something. :-) Browser URL resolution [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). :-)

Comment: [Working here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDcZxK3fQa05CNrHwu7f?p=preview).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes. It's working fine...I don't really get it right. I don't know what is going on here...

Comment: @AbdouBestmood - We've all been there. :-) Maybe take a short break and come back fresh, that sometimes works. It really will be the filename, file location, or (I didn't list this before) your server not being configured to deliver `mylib.js` even though it's configured to deliver `app.js`. That last is unlikely, but for instance if you're rolling your own ExpressJS or Koa server and you have an *explicit* route for `app.js`, then it could be that the server won't serve `mylib.js`. Hope you find it soon! (I'll be interested to know what it is if you don't mind commenting when you've got it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, You're right :) I am actually using Apache server instead (XAMPP). Thus, I am not dealing with ExpressJS, nor I am with Koa...